# Unable to add custom domain to my heroku app

Tags: heroku, ssl-certificate, subdomain, heroku-ssl

When I try to add a custom domain to my app. It all the time give me following error. Can some one point out what wrong am I doing?

Just to clarify I have removed all ssl certificates on all my apps.
But still the error says this

```
Domain "mysubdomain.domain.com" could not be created:
mysubdomain.domain.com conflicts with a wildcard cert on app my-another-app, owned by some-manager@herokumanager.com. Please ask the owner to add this domain.
```

Answer (score 2):

Just in case some one comes looking for the answer here. I noticed that if you have multiple apps scattered across multiple heroku teams using same wild card certificate, only in that case you get this issue. To add the certificate you need to transfer all apps under one team and then add the certificate to your desired app and then transfer them back to their respective teams. It does not add any downtime but it is a lengthy process if you have many apps under one team.